# How can i get the actor birthday by date?

Tags: custom-field

How can i retrive the actor birthday by Date.

How i add the date, i have a custom field with Calendar.
[image]

Now is 20th ... how  can i retrive the Actor By this day

I try this but it wont work

```
<?php // Get today's date in the right format
$todaysDate = date('md');
?>

<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'persoane',
'posts_per_page' =>5,
'meta_key' => 'data_nasterii',
'meta_compare' => '=',
'meta_value' => $todaysDate,
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
) ); ?>

<?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

The meta_key - data_nasterii is the custom field.

Ex: today is 20th Jan 2013

I want to retrivee all actors that are born in 20 th Jan , with the specification  in (38 Years Old (2013-1975=38 years))

EX: 50 Cent - Today is his birthday.
    He is born on 20th Jan 1975 and he has 38 Years .

if anny body know's please post , it will be apreciate , when i found a solution myself i woud post here for others to see. Thanks.

Comment: What format are you storing your dates in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work you need the date stored in the database to match the `$todaysDate` and it probably doesn't. If I am reading your somewhat confusing question correctly then you are storing dates like `20th Jan 2013` but you are matching it against a date that looks like `0120` (January 20). Even if you are are storing dates as a MySQL date, UNIX Timestamp, or as a somewhat more parsable string like `01-20-1975` it still isn't going to match your comparison string.

Your solution is to understand what your data looks like and to search accordingly. I'd recommend storing as a MySQL date or a UNIX timestamp. Either can be programmatically manipulated fairly easily. Without more information-- meaning a better question-- I don't know what else to say.

**Based on additional information in a comment below:**

Use `meta_query` instead of `meta_compare`.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'persoane',
  'posts_per_page' =>5,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'data_nasterii',
            'value' => '__'.$todaysDate,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Used with [`LIKE` the underscore matches exactly one character](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) so if your dates are consistently a two-digit year, two-digit-month, and two-digit day ***and if*** WP_Query passes the `_` through unchanged (I have never tried. I don't know.) that should match *"any two characters followed by your generated date"*. That is not going to be a very efficient query but given your data structure I think that is what you have to go with.

Comment: the date is store like this...yymmdd .. anny help?

This format will determin the value saved to the database and returned via the API

"yymmdd" is the most versatile save format.

Comment: i tried this but it do not work